# Radius of convergence of sum of complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone advise me on how to find radius of convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} [\frac{1}{n^2}+(-2)^n]z^n \ ?$  Thank you.

My attempt: radius of convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2}z^n = 1$ and radius of convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-2)^nz^n \ = \frac{1}{\text{lim sup}|(-2)^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}} =\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Thank you. Is it $\frac{1}{2} \ ? $

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is the smaller of the two power series whose radius of convergence you've found.

The radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is the distance from $0$ to the nearest point to $0$ at which the function of $z$ thus defined cannot be extended to a holomorphic function.  That is an somewhat important theorem in complex variables.  [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functions_are_analytic) tells you how to prove it (although it's not explicitly mentioned until the "Remarks" section).

Your second series has a pole (i.e. approaches $\infty$) at $z=-1/2$.  Thus the radius cannot be more than the distance from $0$ to $-1/2$.  Since there are no other places closer to $0$ where the function behaves badly, that is the radius of convergence.